# MySQL UNION - Replicating a Sub Query

Tags: mysql, union

This is my current query:

```
Select Month as ReqMonth1,
    sum(TotalUsage) As ReqCount1,
    sum(Memberbase) as Club_updates_Records1,
    round(sum(TotalUsage)/sum(Memberbase)*100,0) AS UsagePerc
from(
Select * from (
SELECT
     CAST(DATE_FORMAT(Log_Date, '%b-%y') AS CHAR(100)) AS 'Month',
     CAST(DATE_FORMAT(Log_Date, '%y-%m') AS CHAR(100)) AS 'Monthsort',
     count(Requests.`fk_Members_ID`) AS TotalUsage,
     0 as Memberbase
FROM
     `Requests` Requests INNER JOIN `Members` Members ON Requests.`fk_Members_ID` = Members.`ID`
WHERE
     cast(Requests.`Log_date` as date) BETWEEN date_sub(if($P{StartDate}>'2016-06-01',$P{StartDate},'2016-05-01'), Interval 4 month) and $P{EndDate} AND $P{EndDate}
 AND Members.`Club` = $P{Club}
GROUP BY
     CAST(DATE_FORMAT(Log_Date, '%M-%y') AS CHAR(100)) ) as A

UNION ALL

Select * from (
SELECT
     CAST(DATE_FORMAT(Club_updates.`Update_Date`, '%b-%y') AS CHAR(100)) AS 'Month',
     CAST(DATE_FORMAT(Club_updates.`Update_Date`, '%y-%m') AS CHAR(100)) AS 'Monthsort',
     0 AS TotalUsage,
     ifnull(max(Club_updates.`Records`),1) AS MemberBase
FROM
     `Club updates` Club_updates
WHERE
     cast(Club_updates.`Update_Date` as date) BETWEEN date_sub(if($P{StartDate}>'2016-06-01',$P{StartDate},'2016-05-01'), Interval 4 month) and $P{EndDate} AND $P{EndDate}
 AND Club_updates.`fk_Club` = $P{Club}
GROUP BY  CAST(DATE_FORMAT(Club_updates.`Update_Date`, '%M-%y') AS CHAR(100)) ) As B) as D
group by Month
Order by MonthSort
```

I'm trying to replicate/add another sub query "A" with the change on the Close_Date field instead of the Log_Date field in the WHERE clause.
Basically resulting a sum of both subqueries only in the "ReqCount1" field.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it solved

here's the solution(with an additional condition in the WHERE clause)

```
Select Month as ReqMonth1,
    sum(TotalUsage) As ReqCount1,
    sum(Memberbase) as Club_updates_Records1,
    round(sum(TotalUsage)/sum(Memberbase)*100,0) AS UsagePerc
from(
Select * from (
SELECT
     CAST(DATE_FORMAT(Log_Date, '%b-%y') AS CHAR(100)) AS 'Month',
     CAST(DATE_FORMAT(Log_Date, '%y-%m') AS CHAR(100)) AS 'Monthsort',
     count(Requests.`fk_Members_ID`) AS TotalUsage,
     0 as Memberbase
FROM
     `Requests` Requests INNER JOIN `Members` Members ON Requests.`fk_Members_ID` = Members.`ID`
WHERE
     cast(Requests.`Log_date` as date) BETWEEN date_sub(if($P{StartDate}>'2016-06-01',$P{StartDate},'2016-05-01'), Interval 4 month) and $P{EndDate} AND $P{EndDate}
 AND Members.`Club` = $P{Club} AND Requests.`Request_Type` <> 7
GROUP BY
     CAST(DATE_FORMAT(Log_Date, '%M-%y') AS CHAR(100)) ) as A


UNION ALL
Select * from (
SELECT
     CAST(DATE_FORMAT(Close_Date, '%b-%y') AS CHAR(100)) AS 'Month',
     CAST(DATE_FORMAT(Close_Date, '%y-%m') AS CHAR(100)) AS 'Monthsort',
     count(Requests.`fk_Members_ID`) AS TotalUsage,
     0 as Memberbase
FROM
     `Requests` Requests INNER JOIN `Members` Members ON Requests.`fk_Members_ID` = Members.`ID`
WHERE
     cast(Requests.`Close_Date` as date) BETWEEN date_sub(if($P{StartDate}>'2016-06-01',$P{StartDate},'2016-05-01'), Interval 4 month) and $P{EndDate} AND $P{EndDate}
 AND Members.`Club` = $P{Club} AND Requests.`Request_Type` = 7
GROUP BY
     CAST(DATE_FORMAT(Close_Date, '%M-%y') AS CHAR(100)) ) as G

UNION ALL


Select * from (
SELECT
     CAST(DATE_FORMAT(Club_updates.`Update_Date`, '%b-%y') AS CHAR(100)) AS 'Month',
     CAST(DATE_FORMAT(Club_updates.`Update_Date`, '%y-%m') AS CHAR(100)) AS 'Monthsort',
     0 AS TotalUsage,
     ifnull(max(Club_updates.`Records`),1) AS MemberBase
FROM
     `Club updates` Club_updates
WHERE
     cast(Club_updates.`Update_Date` as date) BETWEEN date_sub(if($P{StartDate}>'2016-06-01',$P{StartDate},'2016-05-01'), Interval 4 month) and $P{EndDate} AND $P{EndDate}
 AND Club_updates.`fk_Club` = $P{Club}
GROUP BY  CAST(DATE_FORMAT(Club_updates.`Update_Date`, '%M-%y') AS CHAR(100)) ) As B) as D
group by Month
Order by MonthSort
```